# Missing 'HKCU:\Network' subkey when browsing registry remotely with PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, powershell, windows-registry

I'm trying to clean up a big mess of random mapped network drives. All our network drives have been mapped on a per-user basis (causing `gwmi win32_mappedlogicaldisk` to come up empty).

I'm trying to remotely access the registry of each workstation and list the contents of `HKCU:\Network`, but when I run this:

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("CurrentUser", $computername)
$Reg.GetSubKeyNames()
```

I get only the following output:

```
AppEvents
Console
Control Panel
Environment
Identities
Keyboard Layout
Printers
Software
UNICODE Program Groups
```

More than a few subkeys are missing. If I run the same command on my local machine all subkeys are displayed.

Why can't I access these subkeys, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` doesn't really exist per se. It's just a projection of `HKEY_USERS\<SID>` of the currently logged on user and is merely provided for your viewing convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The HKCU hives are located in the user's profile directories.  They aren't a part of the main registry hive (%SystemRoot%\System32\Config).

You can get a list of active hives for a machine from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist.

Comment: Interesting. I'm seeing `REGISTRY\USER\.DEFAULT` under `hivelist`. Is it only loading the default values? Can I access HKCU remotely or will I have to get the target user's SID first?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to run the script as the actual user.  Perhaps as an AD logon script?

Comment: Ended up getting the user's SID and running `$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("Users", $computername); $RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("$SID\\Network")` instead. Worked well.